# Is it safe to use ThreadStatic variable in WCF?

Tags: .net, wcf, multithreading

I need to put request specific data in WCF? Is it safe to use ThreadStatic variable in WCF?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895732/where-to-store-data-for-current-wcf-call-is-threadstatic-safe

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to use [OperationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontext.aspx). Here's [an example](http://elegantcode.com/2009/01/17/abstracting-request-state/) of how you could use it to persist some state.