# Where to store data in WCF request

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, session

I'm using a custom username and password validation for my WCF security. Now i would like to store the username during the request so that i can access it later in the method that is called. How do i do that?

Some sample code to describe my problem:

```
public class CustomUserValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator
{
    public override void Validate(string username, string password)
    {
        if (username == "aaa" && password == "bbb")
        {
            // store username where i can get it in method called later.
            return;
        }
        throw new SecurityTokenException("Unknown Username or Password");
    }
}
```

Now the method that is being called:

```
public void WebServiceMethod()
{
    Database.User.Single(c => c.Username == /* username from above */);
}
```

BR
Andreas

Comment: the easiest way is to store it in a static username property. Better way is to write a custom WCF behavior.

Comment: @daryal that is bad on every level; a: WCF is multi-threaded, and b: WCF can use different threads at different points (making thread-static unreliable)

Comment: @MarcGravell you are right on every level:), but in order to answer this question, instance mode and concurreny mode shall be provided. That is why I proposed to write a behavior.

Comment: @daryal why a behaviour? identity has a well-supported model in WCF

Comment: @MarcGravell for a username using principal is ok. But in a complex scenario if you are in need of some correlation parameters, I think it is better to employ custom behaviors. Think of a situation where wcf call headers have identifier fields which are needed to be persisted on database and same parameter is used for correlation purposes.

Answer (score 3):

You would typically do this by issuing a custom "principal", which is done via `IAuthorizationPolicy`; IIRC, the username is made available to the auth-policy via the evaluation-context parameter. A *general* walkthrough to custom principals in WCF is [here](http://leastprivilege.com/2009/04/02/custom-principals-in-wcf-with-geneva/), however you may need to experiment a bit in `Evaluate` to find the incoming username in the evaluation context. In particular, if any of the keys is a "claims" dictionary, look at that. And look at the `.Claims` on the evaluation context - you *should* find a "claim" in their issued by `CustomUserValidator` with the username in it.

I have, however, done **exactly** what you describe in a previous job - and IIRC it worked fine, using the above page as my starting point.

Once you have issued a principal, it will be available, as normal, via:

```
string cn = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

To store data of any kind through a single WCF request, Darin Dimitrov suggests hooking up a simple `IExtension<>` helper class to the current `OperationContext` here: [Where to store data for current WCF call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895732/where-to-store-data-for-current-wcf-call-is-threadstatic-safe#answer-1895958)