# Thread.CurrentThread store custom data such as userid

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

In .net 4, Is it possible to store custom value such as userid in Thread.CurrentThread object?

I am trying to store userid for wcf client on the client side of MessageInspector in AfterReceiveRequest method as follows:

```
request.Headers.Add(MessageHeader.CreateHeader("userid", string.Empty, userid));
```

On the server side I would like to retrieve it in a Thread.CurrentThread in the method AfterReceiveRequest.

Is this possible?

Comment: If you go asynchronous (fairly common in .net 4.5) this may prove to be a problematic way of doing things, because the thread servicing your code could be one of any in the thread pool

Comment: Why don't you go to the headers collection on OperationContext.Current on the server?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where to store data for current WCF call? Is ThreadStatic safe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895732/where-to-store-data-for-current-wcf-call-is-threadstatic-safe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ThreadStatic is not recommended because WCF will randomly use threads from the thread pool and ThreadStatic variables will not be reinitialized when the threads are recycled. Also if you have a session with multiple WCF calls, the same service instance is likely to switch threads from call to call.

**You should create an OperationContext extension.**

See [Where to store data for current WCF call? Is ThreadStatic safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895732/where-to-store-data-for-current-wcf-call-is-threadstatic-safe)