# A way to get global per call properties without using sessions in WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, session

I have a WCF service that I moved from BasicHTTPBinding to wsHttpBinding.

This move has caused a lot of problems.  Mostly because I don't want to participate in the security stuff that is part of wsHttpBinding and turning it off does not work.

The only reason I moved to wsHttpBinding was for session variables.

When I log, I need all the logs for a specific WCF call to have a unique id on them.

Now, I could make this ID a the point the calls come in and pass it to all my methods everywhere.  But I that is really bad design in my book.

**What I am looking for is a way to access a unique per call value (probably a GUID) from any point in my app.  But if I have 1,000 simultaneous calls, I need each call to have its own GUID and only get that one when it asks for it.**

A session works perfectly for this.  But I am getting lots of nasty errors and timeouts with the session turned on, so I figured I would look for a different solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where to store data for current WCF call? Is ThreadStatic safe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895732/where-to-store-data-for-current-wcf-call-is-threadstatic-safe)

Answer (score 1):

You can extend your WCF service by using **IParameterInspector** to inspect the call and generate a GUID for each call. More information is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163302.aspx)