# WCF Request Scope Variables

Tags: .net, wcf

I've been doing some work extending the WCF pipeline of my service using mainly `IOperationInvoker` to implement my own functionality.

I am currently using `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items` to store some variables that I want to be be persisted and available throughout the lifetime of my request (pre method invokation, during webserice method, post method invokation).

This works fine when using the `HTTP` binding, however, I now need to enable `TCP` and `NamedPipes` bindings where the `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items` bag obviously isn't available.

Is there a better place to be storing variables that I only want to be in scope for the current request?

Thanks
David

Comment: Is the data you want to store global or different for each request? You can use AppDomain, but it is global

Comment: Its different per request. I would not want the data to be shared between users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to be linked to `OperationContext` not `HttpContext`. The answer to similar question is already presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895732/where-to-store-data-for-current-wcf-call-is-threadstatic-safe).

Basically you just need to implement IExtension and plug it into WCF. Step-by-step example can be found for example [here](http://blog.hackedbrain.com/2006/09/14/providing-custom-context-to-your-wcf-service-instance/).

Comment: Exactly what I was after. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can setup your service to be Instance context mode of persession.

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)] 
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private string sessionVar;         // for each session
}
```

And then it is up to client to keep the session alive.
In your client you can create a proxy at class level and only close it when you are done with it that way you have sessionVar available.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. Unfortunately, I don't think it's quite what I'm after. I only want the variables to be available for the lifetime of the current request, I do not want them to be available in any subsequent requests.

Really, I'm asking is there a equivalent of System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items which works across all bindings (not just HTTP).