# IDispatchMessageInspector CorrelationState, and accessing it in between

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, idispatchmessageinspector

My AfterRecieveRequest method generates a GUID, and passes this on through the correlationState variable to the BeforeSendReply method.

Between those two calls, a lot happens in my WCF service, and I'd like to access this GUID from within the Webservice methods. Is there a way for me to access this object throughout the WCF service?

The GUID is used for logging purposes, as I am calling on the API of a different application and want to log the results, and log them under the GUID generated in the IDispatchMessageInspector implementation.

for example:

IDispatchMessageInspector implementation:

```
public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
{
    var correlationState = GUID.NewGuid();
    StaticLogger.AddLog(originalMessage, correlationState.ToString(), "WCF-Incoming");
    return correlationState;
}
public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
{
    StaticLogger.AddLog(originalMessage, correlationState.ToString(), "WCF-Outgoing");

}
```

WCF Service:

```
public ResponseObject WCFMethod(string param1, string param2)
{
    ResponseObject response = new ResponseObject();

    Client client = new Client();
    ClientObject result = client.OutsideOperation(param1,param2);
    // here, i would like to log the result object and use the GUID from the correlationstate
    StaticLogger.AddLog(result, correlationState.ToString(), WCF-Internal )

    response.resultAttribute = result;

    return response;
}
```

How would I go on to accomplish this? I've been thinking about using a ThreadStatic attribute so the thread keeps the GUID somewhere in memory, but I am afraid my understanding of this subject is insufficient to implement it right now.

Comment: It goes without saying that I've tried my best to hide irrelevant code, but if I have for some reason omitted something you'd need in order to help me, please tell me.

Comment: You would use a "Current"-object and store the correlationState (or whatever you want to have available during the logical request) in there. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1895958/21567) for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to access the guid between  BeforeSendReply and AfterReceiveRequest,
you could use MessageProperties, the MessageProperties could be accessed when you execute your service.

Below is my test.

```
  public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        var correlationState = Guid.NewGuid();
        request.Properties["myGuid"] = correlationState; // store guid in Properties
        return correlationState;

    }

    public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {

    }
```

Then you could get the guid in your service.

```
 public class ServiceTest : Test
{

    public double add(double a, double b)
    {
         // get the property through IncomingMessageProperties property
        Guid gu = (Guid)OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties["myGuid"];
        Console.WriteLine(gu);

        return a + b;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have already solved my issue by adding the GUID as a header to the incoming message because i was already using OperationContext anyway, but your solution seems better therefore I have marked your response as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this would be what you want, but you can probably add the GUID to your channel message header. Someone already wrote up some useful information on this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1408177/2016162